# How to modify the language data of vuejs project?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I wanted to try https://github.com/gustaYo/vue-chess this project in my pc. Everything well. But I wanted to add another language to the project. I manually added my language but when I run the project again it does not add that language. What can be the problem can anybody help me ?

Comment: What do you mean by saying you added the language?

Comment: src/locale/index.js there is two languages es and en, I added there third languages datas but not showing in the project.

Comment: Have you also updated `lenguajes.js` and any other place where you need to add it?

Comment: updated lenguajes.js but except that i did not know where should i update